# How do I configure svg-sprite to generate the same svg file name with each run?

Tags: svg, command-line-interface, svg-sprite

I'm using the excellent **svg-sprite** as a **cli** to generate an svg sprite from several other svg files. Most of the configuration is understood and I get the svg file and associated css as expected. I'd like the generated svg file to always have the same name, rather than a name which appears to feature a short randomised string, but the configuration for that eludes me. Any suggestions?

- Github repository: https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite
- Configuration tool: https://jkphl.github.io/svg-sprite/#json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of the **svg-sprite** project, Joschi Kuphal, answered this problem for me as follows:

> All you need to do is disable cache busting by setting
>   mode.***mode***.bust = false.

...which works great!